# Conditional average number of tasks in M/M/$\infty$ queue

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Consider an M/M/$\infty$ queue in which the time intervals between task arrivals are i.i.d. exponential with parameter $\lambda$ and task durations are also i.i.d. exponential with parameter $\mu$. Show that, given that $n$ tasks are being processed at time $0$, the expected number of tasks being processed at time $t$ is $ne^{-\mu t} + \frac{\lambda}{\mu}(1 - e^{\mu t}).$

So far, I've found that, when the queue is in equilibrium, the average number of tasks being processed follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$, but I can't make sense of how to arrive at this expression. How does one solve this?

Comment: What governing equations have you formulated for the probability $P(m,t|n,0)$?

Comment: @kevinkayaks What is that notation supposed to mean? If you're asking for someone to provide more detail, it's on you to be clear yourself.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Your notation is a little confusing, but if you mean $\mathbb{P}[m \text{ tasks are being processed at time } t | n \text{ are being processed at time } 0] = P(m, n),$ then I have no governing equations; if I could find that, the expectation would simply be $\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{mP(m, n)}.$

Comment: It's rather standard notation for a probability to get from one state to another (i.e., a propagator or conditional probability) which Jackyooo has interpreted correctly. One way to arrive at the quoted results is to set up a differential difference equation for this probability, then solve it for the first moment and steady state distribution, the latter for example with a generating function approach.

Comment: I would work to set up the differential difference equation for (in your notation Jacky) $P(n,m)$ -- but note this would depend on time. Both results follow from this, both the transient first moment and the steady state distribution. I believe the Cox and Miller 1965 "stochastic processes" book is a great reference for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial solution:

Conditioned on there being $0$ tasks processed at time $0$, the differential-difference equations governing the system size are given by

\begin{align}
p_n'(t) &= -(\lambda+n\mu)p_n(t)+\lambda p_{n-1}(t)+(n+1)\mu p_{n+1}(t),\ n>0\\
p_0'(t) &= -\lambda p_0(t)+\mu p_1(t).
\end{align}
The generating function of the probabilities $\{p_n(t)\}$ is given by
$$
P(z,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n(t)z^n = \exp\left((z-1)(1-e^{-\mu t})\frac\lambda\mu\right).
$$
Expanding this as a Taylor series about $z=0$, we find that
$$
p_n(t) = \frac1{n!}\left((1-e^{-\mu t})\frac\lambda\mu\right)\exp\left(-(1-e^{-\mu t})\frac\lambda\mu\right).
$$
Computing the expectation we find
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n p_n(t) = \frac\lambda\mu(1-e^{-\mu t}).
$$

From here it would remain to show that conditioned on there being $n$ tasks processed at time $0$, the expected number of tasks being processed at time $t$ is the above plus $n e^{-\mu t}$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.